# Flip coordinates for geom_dotplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the flip the x and y coordinates of the following plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Species), binaxis = "y")
```

[image]

First, I tried to change all x and y arguments.

```
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species), binaxis = "x")
```

[image]

The dots start at the bottom instead of at the corresponding species level (y-axis).

Another option is the use `coord_flip()`.

```
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Species), binaxis = "y") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

This works but the point size or spacing between y-axis categories is now not automatically adjusted.

Is there **another way** to do this correctly? Is there a good reason **why the second code block does not work**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the case that the spacing is automatically adjusted in the first plot and not when you use `coord_flip()`. It's just the default dimensions of the first plot happen to be wide enough to correctly handle the spacing in this case.

If you save the first plot with different dimensions e.g. `ggsave("./tmp.png", width = 4, height = 8)`, you will see that you face the same issue with overlap.

Your final plot has three dot density plots stacked on top of each other. This means we need to make it taller than it is wide:

```r
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Species), binaxis = "y") +
  coord_flip()
ggsave("./tmp.png", width = 4, height = 6)
```

[image]

Rather than playing around with the width and height of these plots, I think you should use facets instead. In the above plot, the y-axis is `Species`, but also on the y-axis is the height of the dotted bars, i.e. density. To me the following is much more interpretable:

```r
ggplot(data = iris) +
    geom_dotplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
    facet_wrap(~Species, ncol = 1) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I agree that facets are an excellent alternative and that the overplotting is not an issue of `coord_flip()` but a general problem of `geom_dotplot()`. The only question left unanswered is why my second code block does not work. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @retodomax no I don't see why flipping the coordinates would have the effect it does. The [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html) mention that _this geom has some odd properties_. Maybe this is one of them?

Comment: Thanks, I created a [bug report](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5462)

Answer (score 3):

The `coord_flip` option is fine, but you would need to reduce the default `dotsize` or increase the plot dimensions to get these to fit without overlap.

```r
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Species), binaxis = "y",
               dotsize = 0.4, stackratio = 1.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_gray(base_size = 18)
```

[image]

Another option is to reduce the `binwidth` so that the counts per bin is smaller:

```r
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Species), binaxis = "y",
               dotsize = 0.8, stackratio = 1.3, binwidth = 0.1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_gray(base_size = 18)
```

[image]